# XML External Entities (XXE) attack failing

Tags: php, windows, xxe

Please give me a hint why my code is NOT vulnerable to XXE.

code:

```
$text = $_POST['textarea'];
$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($text);
echo $doc->textContent;
```

testcase 1:

```
<justsomexmltag>Hello world</justsomexmltag>
```

result 1:

```
Hello world
```

So far so good. However, when I'm trying to inject XML code to retrieve a local file's content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE log [
        <!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "test.txt">
    ]>
<log><text>&ent;</text></log>
```

then nothing is printed. "test.txt" is on the same level in the file structure as the php file where I carry out the attack. I have tried

```
<!ENTITY ent SYSTEM file:///"test.txt">
```

as well as

```
<!ENTITY ent SYSTEM file:///full path to the file>
```

but to no avail.

test.txt:

```
This is just a test.
```

Have tried:

```
<test>This is just a test.</test>
```

no results.

Any hints?

reflecting @Paul Crovella, here's an edit:

CP-ing your code resulted in:

DOMDocument::loadXML(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity file:// full path to file name

DOMDocument::loadXML(): Failure to process entity ent in Entity

DOMDocument::loadXML(): Entity 'ent' not defined in Entity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default libxml will not load external entities precisely to avoid this issue. To convince it to do so you'd need to set either [`substituteEntities`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.substituteentities) or [`validateOnParse`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.validateonparse) to `true` prior to loading. E.g.:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE log [
    <!ENTITY ent SYSTEM "test.txt">
]>
<log><text>&ent;</text></log>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->substituteEntities = true;
$dom->loadXML($xml);

echo $dom->textContent;
```

Outputs:

```
This is just a test.
```

Comment: thanks Paul. Made the amendments but still not there. Please see my question edited.

Comment: the file does exist, but what do you mean by "readable by the PHP process". how can I make sure about this?

Comment: Paul, I beg your pardon, the file path was incorrect, missed one folder. Thank you very much!